# Can i lock my android application on and not let user interact with any of the os setings or or software buttons?

Tags: android

I want to create an app that will be used as a commercial in stores on an android tablet. The question is how can i avoid the case where the store seller or the user or whoever closes the app and goes on youtube or other apps? I need this to run from when the tablet starts until it closes or until a certain admin event that will trigger a password check or something similar.

Comment: I dont understand why the downvote, at least if it is a bad qestion or dumb, explain and then downvote, don't gjust throw that there...

Comment: Have you considered screen pinning?

Comment: The target device runs android version 4.4.4.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html

Comment: your question is downvoted probably because you have not done any research yourself

Comment: @TimCastelijns I've done quite a lot of research before asking this. Nothing that i searched for got me on the right track. Maybe i am bad at searching stuff on google or you are too fast on jumping to conclusions. If it is that easy why you take time to send hate and not point me in the right direction? It would be much more helpful if you would help and then tell me how bad and lazy i am or else don't do anything at all. I am just trying to learn here not be patronised.

Comment: @TimCastelijns "In this document

developer.android.com/work/cosu.html: "As an IT administrator, you can configure Android 6.0 Marshmallow and later devices as corporate-owned, single-use (COSU) devices. "

me: "The target device runs android version 4.4.4."

Comment: your question "I want this, I need that" this tells us nothing of all the research you have done, so we can only assume that you haven't. You ask why your question is downvoted and I gave the best possible explanation based on the information present. You don't have to get all upset over nothing just because you don't like the answer. Do read [ask] to prevent this next time

Comment: @AlexandruSandu For KitKat I can suggest nothing but a custom launcher.

Comment: A bit of an overkill but seems like for now it is my only option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont understand why the downvote, at least if it is a bad qestion or dumb, explain and then downvote, don't gjust throw that there

This is not a bad question. Actually they see your formatting, way of asking and lot of things.

Now we move to the solution. 
Magic you need is **KIOSK mode in android app**. I have implemented 2 of my apps. (App for prison and apartment's guard)

**What is KIOSK mode:**

> A Kiosk Mode is implemented by disabling various Android features that
>   can be used to leave your app.

**How to acheive this:**

We will disable following buttons to get KIOSk mode implemented.

- The back button
- The home button
- The recent apps button
- The power button
- The volume buttons

[Here](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/) is the full tutorial with step by step to achieve this. It will take almost half hour. If you don't understand any step just feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try right now and come back with feedback

Comment: @AlexandruSandu Happy to help you :)